# Extracting room voids in a house

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees, probabilistic-algorithms

I am looking to create a series of closed volumes that represent the empty voids made by rooms in a house.

In order to do this, all I have is the raw geometry of all the elements that encapsulate these spaces (walls, floors and ceilings), in the form of closed meshes.

Some additional requirements...

- The elements that encapsulate a space may not fit together perfectly, i.e, the room may not be watertight.
- The shape of the room could be quite complex, i.e the dome like roof of a conservatory.
- Rooms will have openings for doors and windows that will need to be ignored.